# How can I add scrollbars to a datatable?

Tags: css, jsf, datatable

This is my JSF project. I want to add to scrollbar on datatable but I can't. How can I add  scrollbars?

```
<h:dataTable value="#{oneribean.listele()}"
             rows="5" border="0"
             var="pateta"
             class="listele1">

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <big><b> ÖNERİ </b> </big>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{pateta.aciklama}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <big><b> DERS </b> </big>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{pateta.ders}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <big><b> BÖLÜM </b> </big>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{pateta.bolum}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`PrimeFaces`](http://www.primefaces.org/) data table component `<p:dataTable>` to achieve this

```
<p:dataTable var="yourVar" 
             value="#{bean.YourList}" 
             scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150">
       //list your columns here.
</p:dataTable>
```

check [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml).

Comment: but i use to java core ,before i used to primeface and i add to library and xmlns on project so i take org.ricfaces.renderkit error message

Comment: post your exception trace please.